# WordPress: Uploading a new theme to live server

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change a WordPress theme on a live server. I have access to the root folder of WordPress, which contains the main WordPress files, along with all the theme and plugins files, and of course I have access to the database.

So now should I replace the whole WordPress folder which contains the `wp-admin/` content or should I upload theme and plugins and then setup the database?

Please help as its critical to update the live site and to do it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169890/upload-localhost-changes-to-live-server/169931#169931

If you are only making file changes, you should copy the live site and set it up on a local wordpress server. On the local wordpress server, just edit the theme as you like, and when you made your changes. Upload only the theme to your live site.

If you are also making database changes, please read the link in the top of my answer.

Remember to make backup, always make backup, backup is 1. priority in every case. If you screw up, make sure to get back online as fast as possible.

You can use a plugin as 'Duplicator' https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ to copy your live wordpress installation.